# Why constructor Message(const T& data) is conflict with Message(T&& data) when T = int&?

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, move-semantics, overload-resolution

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Message {
    T data;
    explicit Message(T&& data) : data(std::move(data)) {
        std::cout << "Move data" << std::endl;
    }

    explicit Message(const T& data) : data(data) {
        std::cout << "Copy data" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename T>
inline Message<T>*
makeMessage(T&& data) {
    return new Message<T>{std::forward<T>(data)};
}


int main() {
    const int a = 1024;
    auto *copy_msg = makeMessage(a);
}
```

There is a template class `Message` that has two constructors: `Message(T&& data)` and `Message(const T& data)`, And I got the following compile-time errors when I called `makeMessage(a)`.

> error: multiple overloads of 'Message' instantiate to the same signature 'void (const int &&)'
>
> > explicit Message(const T& data) : data(data) {
>
> previous declaration is here
>
> > explicit Message(T&& data) : data(std::move(data)) {

However, It works when I called `make_message(1024)` and `make_message(std::move(a))`.

So why constructor `Message(const T& data)` is duplicate with `Message(T&& data)` when T = int&?

Comment: In your example, `T` is `const int&`, not `int&`.

Comment: @eerorika The error is same when `T` is `int&`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So why constructor Message(const T& data) is duplicate with Message(T&& data) when T = int&?

Because of reference collapsing rules.

There is no such thing as a reference to reference. When `T` is an lvalue reference - let's say `int &`, then syntactically `T &` appears to be a `int & &`. But such type does not exist. The rules of the language say that in such case `T &` collapses into `int &`.

Similarly, there is no such thing as const reference (not to be confused with reference to const, which people sometimes mean when they say const reference). When `T` is an lvalue reference - let's say `int&`, then syntactically `T const` (same as `const T`) appears to be a `int& const` (not to be confused with `int const &`, which is same as `const int &`). But such type does not exist. The rules of the language say that in such case `T const` collapses into `int &`.

C++11 introduced rvalue references, which brings us new collapsing rules. In short, "rvalue reference to rvalue reference" collpses into rvalue reference, but "lvalue reference to any reference", as well as "any reference to lvalue reference" collapse into lvalue reference. This rule is part of the magic behind how forwarding references work.

As such, given `T = int &`, these declare the same function:

```
explicit Message(T&& data)      // type of argument is int &
explicit Message(const T& data) // type of argument is int &
```

---

Bonus: There are also collapsing rules for non-references: There is no such thing as const const type. As such, given `const T` where `T` is `const int`, then it collapses into `const int`. Same goes for `volatile`.

Comment: So It means that I instantiate a class `Message<int&>` rather than `Message<int>` in statement `make_message(a)` ---> `new Message<T>{std::forward<T>(data)};`?

Comment: @daoliker, you instantiate `Message<const int&>`.